# What can hacker do, if he knows my SALTED password?

Tags: passwords

for example, in any website (WORDPRESS or etc..) they store passwords in database, using SALT mehtod (as i know)...
for example:

```
$P$dfwegfwegewgIT03.wewefefweg
```

if hacker got this password and username, can he detect a real password?
shortly, if hacker knows any value in database and my FTP (but the real password is nowhere stored), can he enter the ftp?

Comment: Note that if he had access to the website, he could have compromised Wordpress to send him a copy of the FTP password next time you provide it (to WordPress).

Comment: i mean, i had my FTP files(wordpress instalation) and DATABASE in an archived backup. and Hacker got that backup.. potentially, what he could have done (other than brute-force cracking of a password..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: the salted hash generally contains only the password, not the username, but they are commonly nearly stored.

He will then be able to launch an offline [Brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) attack, trying to find the password that generates that same hash using that same salt.

This attempt may be dictionary-based or exhaustion search-based.

Also, to be allowed access, one MUST have possession of at least 3 pieces of information:

- **Address** (in this case, FTP's address)
- **Username**
- **Password**

If he already has the ftp address and the password, he still has to discover the username. It is possible to use the same technique to make several attempts until he finds a  username that uses the known password in its credential.

The usage of **SALTING** only prevents other accounts with the same password from having the same hash, what would promptly alert the hacker about users sharing the same password.